# Can I lazy init a value depending on constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class where I either know a specific value on creation, or I need to generate it, which is somewhat expensive. Can I generate the value only when it's actually needed?

```
val expensiveProperty: A
constructor(expensiveProperty: A) {
    this.expensiveProperty = expensiveProperty
}
constructor(value: B) {
    // this doesn't work
    this.expensiveProperty = lazy { calculateExpensiveProperty(value) }
}
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36233649/6521116) may helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, but with a twist:

```
class C private constructor(lazy: Lazy<A>) {
    val expensiveProperty by lazy

    constructor(value: B) : this(lazy { calculateExpensiveProperty(value) })
    constructor(expensiveProperty: A) : this(lazyOf(expensiveProperty))
}
```

Note how I kept primary constructor private while leaving secondary constructors public.

Comment: This is nice solution, I did not paid attention at constructor's value while i was answering.